# C# how to return different types from the same virtual function

Tags: c#, oop, virtual-functions

I was wondering how to return different types from the same virtual function with different implementation.
For example one implementation will return int and another will return List.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can try using generics.

Comment: Adding to @Deadzone comment, what is your use case, what code have you implemented so far? How would your base class look like? Do you want to cast potential `object` to more specific types afterwards, or are you fine with specifiyng to generic arguments?

Comment: We can provide an example solution, but first we need to see your actual code.

Comment: @Deadzone I'm keen to know how this can be done with generics!

Comment: @MohamedAhmed I wrote an answer illustrating that

Comment: @Deadzone Great, deserved up-vote :)

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments of your question, you can do that with generics:

```
public class MyBaseClass<T>
{
    public virtual T MyMethod()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class MyIntClass : MyBaseClass<int>
{
    public override int MyMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class MyListClass : MyBaseClass<List<int>>
{
    public override List<int> MyMethod()
    {
        return new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Comment: DeadZone thank you for the response.
I used Genericts as you suggested.
The thing is that I have a function that can call either implementation and return its value (Generics<int> or Generict<List<int>>.
How do I define the return value for that function?

Comment: @SophieTagar Now it's really time to show your code, keeping it so abstract only hinders yourself, limiting the code we can imagine to help

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are truly trying to accomplish and there are likely better or alternative approaches to accomplish your end goal.

However to answer your question you can declare the return type of your virtual method as an object and box value in your overridden method as an object or use generics.

Using an object:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual object MyMethod() { return null; }
}
public class MyIntClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public override object MyMethod() { return (object)1; }
}

public class MyListClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public override object MyMethod() { return (object)new List<string>(); }
}
```

The side effect is you will need to unbox the result.

A better approach to accomplish this result would be to use generics and keep everything strongly typed so you don't need to unbox the result.

```
public class MyBaseClass<T>
{
    public virtual T MyMethod() { return default(t); }
}
public class MyIntClass : MyBaseClass<int>
{
    public override int MyMethod() { return 1; }
}

public class MyListClass : MyBaseClass<List<string>>
{
    public override List<string>> MyMethod() { return new List<string>(); }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thank you for your response. I actually did that but I thought there's a way to return the actual value (like int or string).

Comment: `var` has nothing to do with boxing/unboxing. You would still need to cast from `object` to whatever type is necessary. `var` is simply  syntactic sugar